# Stress Test a LAN (network) connected to the Internet

Tags: networking, qos

Looking to stress test both upstream and downstream capabilities on a LAN that is connected to the Internet to test Quality of Service settings for VoIP traffic on the same network.

Aside from downloading/uploading a popular torrent (such as a Linux distro or Openoffice), any other suggestions?

If not, can you suggest a popular (legal) torrent (or two) that has a lot of seeders and leechers at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Like you said, the best way I can think to max out my bandwidth is by Download and seeding a few popular torrents.  I would recommend the linux distro you are a fan of both the x86 and x86_64 version of the DVDs, like CentOS.  Depending on your internet bandwidth that should fill it.  If not keep adding more distros until you do.

I would opt for these over something a little smaller like OpenOffice because they may finish too soon and thus wouldn't saturate your bandwidth long enough to test against.